# JetBrains IntelliJ IDE to generate code templates

Tags: templates, plugins, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, boilerplate

I there any plugin or way to generate boilerplate codes using JetBrains IDEs

Some plugin similar to the VS Code plugin Blueprint - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=teamchilla.blueprint

Comment: **File Templates** (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html) for files and **Live Templates** (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) for small/in-place code snippets?

Comment: Ok I even need to create a folder which should have boilerplate classes. if you look into the Blueprint plugin if VS code it has such features